# Why are these NO counterexamples for Baire's Theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, baire-category

Baire's Theorem states: Let $X$ be a complete metric space and let $U_n \subset X$ be open and dense ($n \in \mathbb{N}$). Then $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty U_n\subset X$ is dense. 
In the lectures, we discussed the well-known counterexample of the rational numbers. We got two more examples that are NO counterexamples:

- $X=\mathbb{N}\subset \mathbb{R}$ with subspace topology, $U_n:=\mathbb{N}\setminus \{n\}$
- $X=\{\frac{1}{n} \mid n\in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{0\}, U_0:=X\setminus \{0\}, U_n:= X\setminus \{\frac{1}{n}\}$

My problem is that I don't see any difference between the counterexample of the rationals and these two examples, e.g. $\mathbb{N}$ is complete, $\mathbb{N}\setminus \{n\}$ is open since singletons are closed and the closure of $\mathbb{N}\setminus \{n\}\subset \mathbb{N}$ is $\mathbb{N}$ (imo).

Where's my mistake in thinking?

Comment: Can you see why $U_n$ is not dense in the first example?

Comment: What makes you think that the closure of $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{n\}$ in $\mathbb{N}$ is $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila No, I can't. I can choose a sequence in $U_n$ whose limit is either in $U_n$ or in $\mathbb{N}$ and that's the definition of being dense, isn't it?

Comment: What's your sequence in $U_n$ with limit outside of $U_n$? @SafariPark

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Good point! If I remove e.g. 0, I can only choose sequences that either end in 1, -1 or fluctuate between 1 and -1, hence reaching 0 with arbitrary precision is impossible

Comment: @user3482749 combining your comment with the one from Alessando, $\mathbb{N}$  is not the closure of $\mathbb{N}\backslash \{ n \}$ as I cannot find a seq in my $U_n$'s that converge to the missing $n$ (which I would have to reach arbitrary precisely for being a closure)?

Comment: @SafariPark Precisely, yes.

Comment: @user3482749 Great, thanks a lot. Then both examples have the same explanation for why they are no counterexamples!

Comment: @SafariPark : Proper notation is $\mathbb N \setminus \{n\}$ or $\mathbb N \smallsetminus\{n\}$ or $\mathbb N-\{n\},$ not $\mathbb N\backslash\{n\}.$

Comment: The only dense subset of $\Bbb N$ is $\Bbb N$. The only dense subsets of $X$ are $X$ and $X\setminus \{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb N \smallsetminus\{n\}$ is not dense, since no sequence of points in that set approaches $n$ as a limit.